# Subtracting state values - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I create a calculator in react. It stores variable values in the application state. Addition and multiplication works correctly, unfortunately there are errors when subtracting, e.g. 9 - 1 = -8. Why does react change to a negative sign? The same happens during divide.
Link to a working application:
https://codesandbox.io/s/calculator-9dq6i?file=/src/Calc.js
My code:

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Calc extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      prev: "",
      action: "",
      calculation: "",
      result: "",
      current: "",
      disabled: true
    };

    this.addToMemory = this.addToMemory.bind(this);
    this.addition = this.addition.bind(this);
    this.multipliaction = this.multipliaction.bind(this);
    this.subtraction = this.subtraction.bind(this);
    this.divide = this.divide.bind(this);
    this.calculation = this.calculation.bind(this);
  }

  addToMemory = event => {
    let id = event.target.id;

    this.setState(({ result }) => ({
      result: parseInt((result += id))
    }));
  };

  addition = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      prev: this.state.result,
      result: "",
      action: "add",
      disabled: false
    }));
  };

  subtraction = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      prev: this.state.result,
      result: "",
      action: "sub",
      disabled: false
    }));
  };

  multipliaction = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      prev: this.state.result,
      result: "",
      action: "mult",
      disabled: false
    }));
  };

  divide = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      prev: this.state.result,
      result: "",
      action: "div",
      disabled: false
    }));
  };

  calculation = (prev, disabled, result) => {
    if (this.state.action === "add") {
      this.setState(({ prev, mem2, current }) => ({
        current: this.state.result,
        result: parseInt(result) + parseInt(prev)
      }));
      //this.state.result = this.state.result + this.state.prev;
      this.setState({ result: this.state.result + this.state.prev });
    } else if (this.state.action === "sub") {
      this.setState(({ prev, sum, current }) => ({
        current: this.state.result,
        result: parseInt(result) - parseInt(prev)
      }));
      //this.state.result = this.state.result + this.state.prev;
      this.setState({
        result: parseInt(this.state.result) - parseInt(this.state.prev)
      });
    } else if (this.state.action === "mult") {
      this.setState(({ prev, sum, current }) => ({
        current: this.state.result,
        result: parseInt(result) * parseInt(prev)
      }));
      //this.state.result = this.state.result + this.state.prev;
      this.setState({ result: this.state.result * this.state.prev });
    }
    else if(this.state.action === "div"){
      this.setState(({ prev, sum, current }) => ({
        current: this.state.result,
        result: parseInt(result) / parseInt(prev)
      }));
      //this.state.result = this.state.result + this.state.prev;
      this.setState({ result: this.state.result / this.state.prev });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button id="1" onClick={this.addToMemory}>
          1
        </button>
        <button id="2" onClick={this.addToMemory}>
          2
        </button>
        <button id="3" onClick={this.addToMemory}>
          3
        </button>
        <button id="4" onClick={this.addToMemory}>
          4
        </button>
        <button id="5" onClick={this.addToMemory}>
          5
        </button>
        <button id="6" onClick={this.addToMemory}>
          6
        </button>
        <button id="7" onClick={this.addToMemory}>
          7
        </button>
        <button id="8" onClick={this.addToMemory}>
          8
        </button>
        <button id="9" onClick={this.addToMemory}>
          9
        </button>
        <button id="0" onClick={this.addToMemory}>
          0
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.addition}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.subtraction}>-</button>
        <button onClick={this.multipliaction}>*</button>
        <button onClick={this.divide}>/</button>
        <button disabled={this.state.disabled} onClick={this.calculation}>
          =
        </button>

        <p>MEM:{this.state.prev}</p>
        <p>SUM:{this.state.calculation}</p>
        <p>RES:{this.state.result}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Calc/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can put your running example here on site using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). *Edit:* I did it for you, since you'd included all of the necessary code in the question (nice one!).

Comment: I doubt it's the actual problem, but there's an anti-pattern in the code above: You're using the callback version of `setState` and using `this.state` in the callback. You don't want to do that. Instead, use the state object your callback receives: `this.setState(state => ({prev: state.result, /*...*/}));` State updates may be asynchronous and may stack up, so `this.state` may be (effectively) stale by the time the state callback is called. (You're right to use the callback form, though; you definitely want that form when creating state based on previous state.)

Comment: Your best bet here is to use the debugger built into your IDE or browser to step through your code. Set a breakpoint on your subtraction logic and look at the values of the variables as of when you use them, etc. A couple of site notes for you (which aren't the problem): 1. You might consider `switch` rather than a long series of `if`/`else if`. 2. You're creating your handlers as arrow functions on instance properties, which means you don't have to `bind` them, since they close over `this`. (But I'd recommend making them actual methods instead, and keeping the `bind` calls.)

Comment: The order of operations is important with subtraction and division (trying 8/2 with your code gave 0.25!) You should put `parseInt(prev)` before `parseInt(result)` in all operations.